# Row by row pixel checking of an image

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

I took the difference of two consecutive frames of a video. What I got (as you know) a black frame except the moving objects. The moving objects are white. I want to count the number of white pixels in the frame. I mean, I want to go through the image row by row and if the value of the ith pixel is greater than a specified number (say 50) then they must be stored in an array. Later on I will use this array to check if there is actually an object or just a noise. For example, if a car is moving in the video then after frame differencing I will check each pixel of the frames, containing the car, row by row, to detect that car. As a result when there is a moving car in the video the pixels' values are greater than 0 after frame differencing. Any idea how can I sum all the pixels of the moving car that will enable me to decide if it is a car or just a noise.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: computer vision questions usually benefit a lot from embedded example images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably find that the difference is non-trivial. For instance, you will probably find that the biggest difference is near the edges of the car, perpendicular to the movement of the car. One of those two edges will have negative values, one positive. Therefore, the biggest advantage of the "difference image" is that you restrict your search area. In isolation it's not very useful.

So, what should you do? Well, use an edge detection algorithm on the normal image, and compare the edge found there with the 2 edges found in the difference image. The edges belonging to the car will connect the 2 edges from the difference image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use blob detection: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/blobDetection.html
to detect a blob of white pixels in each "difference image". Once you have the blobs you can find their center by finding the average of their pixel positions. Then you can find the path swept out by these centers and check it against some criterion.

Without knowing more about your images I cannot suggest a criterion, but for example if you are watching them move down a straight road you might expect all the points to be roughly co-linear. In this case, you can get the gradient and a point where a blob is found and use the point-gradient form of a line to get the lines equation:

```
y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)
```

For example given a point (4, 2) and gradient 3 you would get

```
y - 2 = 3(x - 4)
y = 3x - 2
```

You can then check all points against this line to see if they lie along it.